# Anyway to optimize pdf programmatically?

Tags: vba, python-2.7, pdf, ms-word

I would like to programmatically optimize (i.e. "Save As Reduced Size PDF" in Acrobat Pro 10) a series of PDF files. I would prefer to do this from python 2.7.5 if possible, if not from python then perhaps VBA Word, and my last preference would be to do this from another programming mechanism.

Ideas?

Comment: For my need i used batch-file with nconvert(non-commercial)+GhostScript: extracting all pages to PNG-format files; packing all PNG-files to one pdf. By reducing color size and dimension it got very small size (but still readable).

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be to look at `pdfsizeopt`.

The Python program is meant to act as a PDF file size optimizer. It can be used to convert larger pdfs to smaller ones and supports a commandline interface that you could call.

Details:

> pdfsizeopt is a program for converting large PDF files to small ones.
>   More specifically, pdfsizeopt is a free, cross-platform command-line
>   application (for Linux, Mac OS X, Windows and Unix) and a collection
>   of best practices to optimize the size of PDF files, with focus on
>   PDFs created from TeX and LaTeX documents. pdfsizeopt is written in
>   Python, so it is a bit slow, but it offloads some of the heavy work to
>   its faster (C, C++ and Java) dependencies. pdfsizeopt was developed on
>   a Linux system, and it depends on existing tools such as Python 2.4,
>   Ghostscript 8.50, jbig2enc (optional), sam2p, pngtopnm, pngout
>   (optional), and the Multivalent PDF compressor (optional) written in
>   Java.

Reference:

http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be [Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf/python). It is a paid REST API but provides 150 free monthly API calls. Currently, it compresses PDF documents from Cloud storage(Aspose default storage/Amazon S3/Google Drive/ Azure storage/ Dropbox/ FTP Storage). In near future, we are planning to support compressing PDF from the request body(stream).

```
import os
import asposepdfcloud
from asposepdfcloud.apis.pdf_api import PdfApi
from shutil import copyfile

# Get App key and App SID from https://cloud.aspose.com
pdf_api_client = asposepdfcloud.api_client.ApiClient(
    app_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    app_sid='xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx')

pdf_api = PdfApi(pdf_api_client)
temp_folder="Temp"

#upload PDF file to storage

data_file = "C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf"
remote_name="02_pages.pdf"
result_name="02_pages_compressed.pdf"

pdf_api.upload_file(temp_folder + '/' + remote_name,data_file)

optimize_options = asposepdfcloud.models.OptimizeOptions(
                allow_reuse_page_content=False,
                compress_images=True,
                image_quality=100,
                link_duplcate_streams=True,
                remove_unused_objects=True,
                remove_unused_streams=True,            
                unembed_fonts=True)
opts = {
            "options" : optimize_options,
            "folder" : temp_folder
        }

response = pdf_api.post_optimize_document(remote_name, **opts)

#download PDF file from storage
response_download = pdf_api.download_file(temp_folder + '/' + remote_name)
copyfile(response_download, 'C:/Temp/' + result_name)
print(response)
```

P.S: I'm a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ghostscript to batch process pdfs.  This VBA works in Word and Excel.  It asks for a Source directory and a Target directory. The .bat file is created and stored in the Source folder and then you can execute it. I probably will make this script more robust and will update here when I do.

[Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/index.html)

```
Sub gsPDF_Bat()
  
    'Summary of -dPDFSETTINGS:

    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen lower quality, smaller size. (72 dpi)
    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook for better quality, but slightly larger pdfs. (150 dpi)
    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" setting (300 dpi)
    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" setting (300 dpi)
    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/default selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file
      
    Dim ProofsFolder As String
    Dim CompressFolder As String
    Dim exePath As String

    exePath = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\"

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            ProofsFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            CompressFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
        
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim CurrFile As Object

  
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(ProofsFolder)
       
    Open ProofsFolder & "\gsPDF-Compress.bat" For Output As #1
       
    For Each CurrFile In folder.Files
        FName = CurrFile.Name
        CurrFileExt = Right(FName, 4)
            Debug.Print CurrFileExt

            If CurrFileExt = ".pdf" Then

                backNum = InStrRev(CurrFile, "\", -1)
                FName = Mid(CurrFile, (backNum + 1))

                Print #1, exePath & "gswin64 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -r300 -dUseCIEColor -sOutputFile=""" & CompressFolder & "\" & FName & """ """ & CurrFile & """"
            End If
    Next
    Close #1

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As in my previous answer, still using Ghostscript.  I noticed that when we would select 1,000 or so pdfs to batch optimize, Excel would take a few minutes to complete the bat file.  I wrote up a different version which creates a new sheet, puts together the bat file, and then saves it.  Even with 1,000 records this only takes a few seconds.

This script will not run in Word, as it needs to create a new Excel Sheet.  The script could be updated to work with a Word doc instead.
.prn format has a line limit, so I needed to line break the commands with a "^"

```
Sub gsPDF_Bat()
 'https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#distillerparams
    
    Dim ProofsFolder As String
    Dim CompressFolder As String
    Dim OrigSheet As String
    Dim exePath As String
    Dim CmdLine, CmdLine2, CmdLine3 As String
    
    exePath = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\"

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            ProofsFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    If ProofsFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
        Debug.Print ProofsFolder
    End If
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            CompressFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    If CompressFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
        Debug.Print CompressFolder
    End If
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim CurrFile As Object

  
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(ProofsFolder)
       
    cell = 0
    OrigSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "temp"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    For Each CurrFile In folder.Files
        FName = CurrFile.Name
        CurrFileExt = Right(FName, 4)
            Debug.Print CurrFileExt

            If CurrFileExt = ".pdf" Then
                cell = cell + 1
                
                Debug.Print "CurrFile Found: " & CurrFile

                backNum = InStrRev(CurrFile, "\", -1)
                Debug.Print "backNum: " & backNum
                FName = Mid(CurrFile, (backNum + 1))
                Debug.Print FName
                
                ' ^ allows a line break on a DOS command
            CmdLine = exePath & "gswin64 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dUseCIEColor -^"
            CmdLine2 = "sOutputFile=""" & CompressFolder & "\z" & FName & """^"
            CmdLine3 = " " & """" & CurrFile & """"

            Sheets("temp").Range("A" & cell).value = CmdLine
            cell = cell + 1
            Sheets("temp").Range("A" & cell).value = CmdLine2
            cell = cell + 1
            Sheets("temp").Range("A" & cell).value = CmdLine3    
            End If
    Next

    Sheets("temp").Select
    Sheets("temp").Copy
 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        ProofsFolder & "\gsPDF Compress.bat", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Sheets("temp").Delete
    Sheets(OrigSheet).Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing

End Sub
```